# Validation of WCF Data Contract

Tags: wcf, data-annotations

I need to validate data coming from request. What I have done so far is:

1. Added reference to `DevTrends.WCFDataAnnotations` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`
2. Placed *[ValidateDataAnnotationsBehavior]* in service implementation
3. Placed attribute on data like:
                                                                         `private int items=0;`
   `[DataMember]
   [Range(0, 6, ErrorMessage = "Items must be an integer between 0 and 6")]`

   ```
   public int Items
   {
       get { return items; }
       set { items = value; }
   }
   ```

   This is all that's needed according to http://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/. What am I missing?  When I send a SoapUI request it shows **'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message'**

Comment: You might want to check the formatting of your code here. I've suggested an edit which you can check.

Comment: My edit was rejected due to a conflict with your edit. It's fine, you can just check that the formatting is correct.

Comment: ok i've done it . thanks @CharlieEgan